# Components are invisible in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Could you tell me please, why components like JPanel etc. are not visible when added to a JFrame? Here is my code:

```
public class GUI{
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private void createAndShowGUI()  {

    final ImageIcon zielonaikona = new ImageIcon("kulazielona.png");
    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("MasterMind");
    JRadioButton zielony = new JRadioButton(zielonaikona);
    zielony.setSelected(true);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton akceptuj = new JButton("Akceptuj");

    akceptuj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(zielonaikona);            
            panel.add(label2);
        }
    });      


    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    panel.add(akceptuj);
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    panel.add(zielony);
    JLabel label = new JLabel (zielonaikona); 
    panel.add(label);
    frame1.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame1.getContentPane().add(akceptuj);
    frame1.getContentPane().add(zielony);
    frame1.setSize(200, 300);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI kk = new GUI();
    kk.createAndShowGUI();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add your controls to the `JFrame` as well as the `JPanel` `panel`, so they will only appear in the last container to which they were added, namely the frame. Also because you add them in the default `BorderLayout.CENTER` position each one displaces the last so you are only left with one component displayed (the `JRadioButton` `zielony`)

To fix, remove the lines:

```
  frame1.getContentPane().add(akceptuj);
  frame1.getContentPane().add(zielony);
```

---

*Aside:* When adding new components *on the fly* (i.e. the `JLabel` added in the `ActionListener`), don't forget to call:

```
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: It's also confusing to change the layout between adding components to the `JPanel`. Try not to do that. The original code can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: @reimeus The OP "shouldn't" need to call revalidate and repaint as they don't set the frame visible until AFTER they finished adding the components, which makes a nice change. +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was referring to the `JLabel` added in the `ActionListener`...:)

Comment: @reimeus, Ah, we'll that makes more sense ;P

Comment: @Reimeus, tnank you for help and notice about repaint() and revalidate(), it works. But I noticed, that panel.revalidate() also works alone.

Answer (score 1):

The button and the radio button are added twice, to the panel and to the frame. You didn't set the layout on the frame but I think it has a default one. I just don't remember what kind.

Here is your code that is wrong.

```
 panel.add(akceptuj);
 panel.add(zielony);
```

and

```
 frame1.getContentPane().add(akceptuj);
 frame1.getContentPane().add(zielony);
```

Comment: A component can only reside within one container. Adding the components to a second container will remove them from the first. The default layout for. Frame is normally BorderLayout and for JPanel it's normally FlowLayout

Comment: @MadProgrammer Added a note that the code I showed was the part that was wrong in the original question.

Comment: @Lee Meador and MadProgrammer thank you, I didn't know that JFrame has a default layout.